# django: Filter objects by multiple key,value pairs of one foreign key model

Tags: django

I would like to know which is the best way to filter objects, that have multiple parameter/value pairs of one foreign model.
Example:

```
class Car(models.Model):
    name = models.SlugField("Name")

class Parameter(models.Model):
    name  = models.SlugField()
    value = models.TextField(blank=True)
    car   = models.ForeignKey('Car', related_name = 'parameters')
```

Let's say i have some cars that have these 3 specific parameters: (name=color, value=blue); (name=tire, value=Goodyear); (name=seat, value=leather)

What would be the best way to filter all cars that have these certain parameter/value combinations?
What i have done by now is to filter one parameter/value pair after the other in a loop. But this takes to much time and i'm sure there is a better way. Somehow by aggregations perhaps...?

By now the only way i get it to work, is:

```
 Job.objects.filter( Q(parameters__name="tire", parameters__value="Goodyear") ).filter( Q(parameters__name="color", parameters__value="blue") ).filter( Q(parameters__name="seat", parameters__value="leather") )
```

Answer (score 4):

If I understand you correctly you are looking to OR some query filters, by default Django ANDs all filters together. To introduce ORing you should use Q objects. In your example you would need a combination of ANDing (&) and ORing (|):

```
from django.db.models import Q

queryset = Car.objects.filter(
    (Q(parameters__name='color') & Q(parameters__value='blue')) | 
    (Q(parameters__name='tire') & Q(parameters__value='Goodyear')) |
    (Q(parameters__name='seat') & Q(parameters__value='leather'))
)
```

Note the reverse lookup from Car to Parameter.

This should equate to get me all Cars that have parameters: name=color AND value=blue OR parameters: name=tire AND value=Goodyear OR parameters: name=seat AND value=leather.

Comment: No, i need ANDing of these parameters. I only want to get those cars who 1. have these three parameters ( i.e. there maybe cars who have not a parameter color etc.) and 2. they have exactly the given values. I've already tried it the way you did with &, bu that does not work.

Answer (score 3):

Use the Q option.

```
from django.db.models import Q

query = Q()
query &= (Q(name='color') & Q(value='blue'))
query &= (Q(name='tire') & Q(value="Goodyear"))
query &= (Q(name="seat") & Q(value="leather"))

# List : Force the db call to one call
result = list(Parameters.objects.filter(query))
for c in result:
   c.car
```

Should works.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I have already treid this before, it does not work this way.

Comment: In your case, the only good response is yours: A filter chain. I've tried on a small db.

But in your case perhaps you should reconsider the db design. If you have two cars A and B and one tires maker C, you'll have 2 C entries in your database. 

Please consider the ManyToManyField : 

[code]
class Car(models.Model):
  name = models.SlugField("Name")
  parameters = models.ManyToManyFields('Parameter')
[/code]

And it works.